# Navigation button changes color to grey after transition

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can make push transition with 'Add button' but I need also do it programmatically. When I do it programmatically and then I go back 'Add button' becomes grey. I debugged it and I can see that the _defualtAttributes have changed in _titleView. The color value has changed. Why is it changing? How to prevent from it? It looks confusing.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AddPalletViewController * addPalletViewController = [self addPalletViewControllerInstance];
    [addPalletViewController setEditMode:true];
    [addPalletViewController setEditModeRowValue: [[self.datasource objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectAtIndex: [[[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]intValue]]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController: addPalletViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Pls Share some code, so that picture becomes clear !

Answer (score 0):

Put This code in instead of yours..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
AddPalletViewController * addPalletViewController = [self addPalletViewControllerInstance];
[addPalletViewController setEditMode:true];
[addPalletViewController setEditModeRowValue: [[self.datasource objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectAtIndex: [[[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]intValue]]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController: addPalletViewController animated:YES];
//Will deselect your row...
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Nothing has changed...Now in ViewDidAppear I change the color of button.